# Fill in form with append and bind

Tags: jquery, append, bind

Currently I'm working on a project that has 1 register form. In this form it is allowed to add multiple members in 1 go. The first member is required, the others aren't. To add more members I use 'append' from jQuery that adds the form for the second and third member perfectly.

Now, I want to add a piece of code that fills in my streetname and city automatically when I fill in the postalcode.

I use jquery with json to fill in some form fields for me. I use this piece of code:

```
        $('input[name=postcode_1]').change(function(){
            //100420//
            b_postcode = $('input[name=postcode_1]').val();
            $.getJSON('/inc/getPostcodeInfo.php', {postcode:b_postcode}, function(data) {
                    $('input[name=adres_1]').val('');
                    $('input[name=plaats_1]').val('');              
                $.each(data, function(index, array) {   
                //  alert(array['straat']);                     
                    $('input[name=adres_1]').val(array['straat']);
                    $('input[name=plaats_1]').val(array['woonplaats']);
                })

            }); 
        });
```

This works perfectly for 1 member but when I add the second and third member it doesn't work. I read that I'd need to use the function 'bind' which is what I used for the second and third member like so:

```
html.bind('change', '[name=postcode_'+ count +']', function(){

            b_postcode = $('input[name=postcode_'+ count +']').val();
            $.getJSON('/inc/getPostcodeInfo.php', {postcode:b_postcode}, function(data) {
                    $('input[name=adres_'+ count +']').val('');
                    $('input[name=plaats_'+ count +']').val('');                
                $.each(data, function(index, array) {   
                //  alert(array['straat']);                     
                    $('input[name=adres_'+ count +']').val(array['straat']);
                    $('input[name=plaats_'+ count +']').val(array['woonplaats']);
                })

            }); 
        });
```

(Whenever a new member is added count becomes count++)

This seems to only work for the last member added. How can I make this work so I can automatically fill in the streetname and city for all members?

Information members:

Member 1 - postalcode: 1111 AA

Member 2 - portalcode: 2222 BB

Member 3 - postalcode: 3333 CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (for jquery >= 1.7)

```
$(document).on('change', '[name^=postcode_]', function(){
    var $this = $(this), count = $this.attr('name').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

    b_postcode = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON('/inc/getPostcodeInfo.php', {postcode:b_postcode}, function(data) {
        $('input[name=adres_'+ count +']').val('');
        $('input[name=plaats_'+ count +']').val('');                
        $.each(data, function(index, array) {   
            //  alert(array['straat']);                     
            $('input[name=adres_'+ count +']').val(array['straat']);
            $('input[name=plaats_'+ count +']').val(array['woonplaats']);
        })

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I do have a question though. Could you tell me what this piece does: `$this.attr('name').match(/(\d+)/)[1];`

Comment: it is a regex to find out the `count` value from the name attribute